# Can the 'Domain' of set-cookie valued any domain？

Tags: http, cookies, https, setcookie

Can the 'Domain' of set-cookie valued any domain？

eg:

when login `www.google.com`,

a xhr to `facebook.com` is requested

and responsed with a response Header `set-cookie:aaa=1;domain=twitter.com`.

Will the cookie be set to `domain=twitter.com` successfully？

Comment: if the domain is unset , which domain will the cookie be set to?

Answer (score 2):

**No. It cannot.** HTTP clients, user-agents and web browsers are required to reject any `Set-Cookie` header that specifies a `Domain=` that does not match the Origin of the current document.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

> A cookie for a domain that does not include the server that set it should be rejected by the user agent.
>
> The following cookie will be rejected if set by a server hosted on `originalcompany.com`:
>
> ```
> Set-Cookie: qwerty=219ffwef9w0f; Domain=somecompany.co.uk
> ```
>
> A cookie for a sub domain of the serving domain will be rejected.
>
> The following cookie will be rejected if set by a server hosted on `example.com`:
>
> ```
> Set-Cookie: sessionId=e8bb43229de9; Domain=foo.example.com
> ```

The `Set-Cookie` header's `Domain=` parameter is to allow a subdomain's website to allow its cookies to be used by a parent domain website, but not the other way around.

Note that browsers are aware of the structure of ccTLDs, so a website at `example.co.uk` cannot use `Set-Cookie, Domain=co.uk`, but a website at `subdomain.example.co.uk` *can* use `Set-Cookie, Domain=example.co.uk`.

Comment: So in my case, `set-cookie:aaa=1;domain=facebook.com` will be allowed; `set-cookie:aaa=1;domain=www.google.com`  and `set-cookie:aaa=1;domain=twitter.com`  will be rejected?
Am i right?

Comment: @WilkinWendy They would all be rejected due to CORS policies which is unrelated to the `Set-Cookie` header's `Domain=` parameter.

Comment: If cors is configured  correctly,what the result will be ?
I mean use server-side CORS solution.